# Best way to get a date with .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, date

I'm getting a string back from my page and I want to make sure it's a date. This is what I have so far (it works) and I just want to know if this is the "best" way to do it. I'm using .NET 4.

```
int TheMonth =0;
int TheDay = 0;
int TheYear = 0;
DateTime NewDate;

var TheIncomingParam = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT").ToString();

char[] TheBreak = { '/' };
string[] TheOutput = TheIncomingParam.Split(TheBreak);

try { TheMonth = Convert.ToInt32(TheOutput[0]); }
catch { }

try { TheDay = Convert.ToInt32(TheOutput[1]); }
catch { }

try { TheYear = Convert.ToInt32(TheOutput[2]); }
catch { }

if (TheMonth!=0 && TheDay!=0 && TheYear!=0)
{
        try { NewDate = new DateTime(TheYear, TheMonth, TheDay); }
        catch { var NoDate = true; }
}
```

Comment: have a good pick-up line.

Comment: What version of asp.net are you using?

Comment: Start by asking her out.

Comment: 1: Be attractive.
2: Don't be unattractive.
3: Have money.

Comment: lol. This was flagged by the mod tool due to a huge number of page views. In the future, you may want to be more careful how you title your questions. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. Or, maybe not, LOL. He might have gotten more attention by the title ;-)

Comment: @Josh - Oh, he *definitely* got more attention.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use one of the `Parse` methods defined on the `DateTime` structure.

These will throw an exception if the string is not parseable, so you may want to use one of the [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) methods instead (not as pretty - they require an out parameter, but are safer):

```
DateTime myDate;
if(DateTime.TryParse(dateString, 
                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                  DateTimeStyles.None, 
                  out myDate))
{
   // Use myDate here, since it parsed successfully
}
```

If you know the exact format of the passed in date, you can try using the `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` that take date and time format strings ([standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)) when trying to parse the date string.

Comment: Ah! It's already built into the framework! Thanks. BTW, I got my page to work: instead of page methods to send a parameter, I got it to work with __doPostBack.

Comment: @frenchie - Glad to hear you got it sorted... and the BCL has loads of such goodies built in. Spend some time reading the documentation on MSDN, you never know what you will find.

Comment: Yes, there's a lot built-in that can help, but only if you know it exists in the first place. The other day I discovered extension methods and these are awesome!!

Answer (score 2):

How about [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) and [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)?

The first one uses the current cultures date format.

Answer (score 1):

.NET gives us a `datetime.parse`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

and a `datetime.tryparse`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx

which both are a good way to parse dates from strings

Answer (score 0):

I would just TryParse the input string:

```
    private bool ParseDateString()
    {
        var theIncomingParam = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT").ToString(); 

        DateTime myDate;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(theIncomingParam, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate))
        {
            int TheMonth = myDate.Month;
            int TheDay = myDate.Day;
            int TheYear = myDate.Year;

            // TODO: further processing of the values just read

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```